# VBA: ParamArray() with sets of values instead of individual values

Tags: vba, excel

In Excel VBA, I understand how to use `ParamArray()` but is there a way to require sets of parameters instead of just one at a time. For example; `sum(val1, val2, val3, ...)` lets you enter one value at a time, but with `sumifs(A:A, rng1, val1, rng2, val2, ...)` you are required to put the `rng` and `val` as a set. Is there a way to do that with user defined functions?

I feel like it is just something I will need to do in the code but I would like it to correct from the start.

```
Function foo(bar As String, ParamArray names() As String, ParamArray attributs() As Range) As String
    ...
End Function
```

in the cell

```
=foo("hello", "name", A2:A5, "age", B2:B5, "address", C2:C5)
```

Comment: if no type is specified to the paramarray variable, then any type can be passed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20783170/pass-array-to-paramarray

Comment: If you need your ParamArray to contain pairs of values then check the ubound and raise an error if it's even.  Pretty sure there's no up-front way to "force" the user to call it using the correct number of arguments.